# Compilation error when deploying my Ember/Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ember.js, deployment

I have a rails 5 ember 2.17 app that was previously being successfully deployed in production. The deployment is done with ember-cli-rails.

During asset compilation I have the following error :

```
=================================================================================

ENV Summary:

  TIME: Mon Jul 08 2019 15:40:33 GMT+0200 (CEST)
  TITLE: ember
  ARGV:
  - /usr/bin/node
  - /srv/production/www/placedemarche/releases/20190708133545/marketadmin/node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember
  - build
  - --environment
  - production
  - --output-path
  - /srv/production/www/placedemarche/releases/20190708133545/tmp/ember-cli/apps/marketadmin
  EXEC_PATH: /usr/bin/node
  TMPDIR: /tmp
  SHELL: /bin/bash
  PATH:
  - /srv/production/www/placedemarche/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin
  - /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin
  - /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/bin
  - /home/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin
  - /home/admin/.rvm/bin
  - /usr/local/sbin
  - /usr/local/bin
  - /usr/sbin
  - /usr/bin
  - /sbin
  - /bin
  - /usr/games
  - /usr/local/games
  PLATFORM: linux x64
  FREEMEM: 1093439488
  TOTALMEM: 3149369344
  UPTIME: 16758723
  LOADAVG: 0.8134765625,0.71240234375,0.56201171875
  CPUS:
  - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz - 2200
  - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz - 2200
  - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz - 2200
  - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz - 2200
  - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz - 2200
  - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz - 2200
  ENDIANNESS: LE
  VERSIONS:
  - ares: 1.10.1-DEV
  - http_parser: 2.8.0
  - icu: 58.2
  - modules: 48
  - napi: 3
  - node: 6.14.3
  - openssl: 1.0.2o
  - uv: 1.16.1
  - v8: 5.1.281.111
  - zlib: 1.2.11

ERROR Summary:

  - broccoliBuilderErrorStack: [undefined]
  - code: [undefined]
  - codeFrame: [undefined]
  - errorMessage: Unexpected identifier
  - errorType: [undefined]
  - location:
    - column: [undefined]
    - file: [undefined]
    - line: [undefined]
  - message: Unexpected identifier
  - name: SyntaxError
  - nodeAnnotation: [undefined]
  - nodeName: [undefined]
  - originalErrorMessage: [undefined]
  - stack: /srv/production/www/placedemarche/releases/20190708133545/marketadmin/node_modules/@embroider/core/src/to-broccoli-plugin.js:18
        async build() {
              ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/production/www/placedemarche/releases/20190708133545/marketadmin/node_modules/@embroider/core/src/index.js:9:28)

=================================================================================
```

I am not sure what's the next step to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't think Embroider supports node 6. Try upgrading your build environment to node 10, which is used by Embroider in it's own CI pipeline. I would not recommend combining an experimental build tool like Embroider with an outdated version of Ember.

Comment: I cannot find embroider in package.json or package-lock.json. What should I do to remove it?

Comment: `npm ls @embroider/core` or `yarn why @embroider/core` should do the trick. But I would not try to remove it, if it's included by an addon. Node 6 is not supported anymore. You should upgrade your build environment.

Comment: I am looking for where node 6 is, but on the server node -v is 8.11.4

Comment: Thx @jelhan, it was the deployment tool ignoring NVM.

Comment: Added it as an answer as well for the next ones coming via google. Embroider gets more and more attention so more people might be hit by that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could see in the error log that the build used node 6:

```
ENV Summary:
  VERSIONS:
  - node: 6.14.3
```

Node 6 is not supported anymore. It's LTS supported ended at April 30, 2019. The ember ecosystem drops support for it as well.

[Embroider](https://github.com/embroider-build/embroider) is an experimental build tool for Ember. It's only tested against Node 10 so far.

I would recommend upgrading your build environment to a recent version of node.